# How can I achieve a JFormattextfield accepting only number and limited character

Tags: java, swing

I have two `JFormattedTextField` for variables Amount and Account No .
**Purpose** :

1. Both field must accept only number
2. Acc No can take up to 15 characters which can vary from 8-15. Similarly Amount can have up to 6 characters and also varies.

To achieve this I used `MaskFormatter` but the problem is the "Variation". Some acc is 15 digits, some are 12 digits so while using `MaskFormatter` limited to 15, it becomes mandatory to enter 15 digits otherwise inserted data disappears during runtime when we leave the `JFormattedTextField`

Is there any way to achieve both scenario in java swing?
Please suggest me

Comment: You need to create a document filter and add it to the textfields document (don't forget to cast to AbstractDocument when you do).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `DocumentFilter`. Then you can customize the filter for your specific requirement.

A basic example to get you started:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.text.*;

public class DigitFilter extends DocumentFilter
{
    @Override
    public void insertString(FilterBypass fb, int offset, String text, AttributeSet attributes)
        throws BadLocationException
    {
        replace(fb, offset, 0, text, attributes);
    }

    @Override
    public void replace(FilterBypass fb, int offset, int length, String text, AttributeSet attributes)
        throws BadLocationException
    {
        Document doc = fb.getDocument();

        // add check here check the length of the text currently in the document
        // with the length of your text String to make sure the total is not above the maximum
        // you should modify the class to pass a paramenter when you create the class for the
        // maximum length so the class can be reused

        if (isDigit( text ))
            super.replace(fb, offset, length, text, attributes);
        else
            Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();
    }

    private boolean isDigit(String text)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++)
        {
            if (! Character.isDigit( text.charAt(i) ) )
                return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI()
    {
        JTextField textField = new JTextField(15);
        AbstractDocument doc = (AbstractDocument) textField.getDocument();
        doc.setDocumentFilter( new DigitFilter() );

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Integer Filter");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLayout( new java.awt.GridBagLayout() );
        frame.add( textField );
        frame.setSize(220, 200);
        frame.setLocationByPlatform( true );
        frame.setVisible( true );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater( () -> createAndShowGUI() );
/*
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
*/
    }

}
```

You will need to add separate logic (external to the DocumentFilter) to make sure the account length is at least 8 digits before you do your processing.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Implementing a Document Filter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html#filter) for an example of a filter that limits the number of characters. The logic from there needs to be combined with the example here.

Comment: Thanks camickr and Abra . I am researching on document filter to get the result.i will update it on success

Comment: Hi camickr , I successfully finished above functionality. Thanks to you @camickr

Comment: .Hi Camickr, as you said i implemented DocumentFilter to make 2 textfield only accept numbers and limited character. Now new problem, after submitting all data to database i am trying to clear all textfield by setText("").Here it only not working in that two field. I guess because of implementation of limit character code.

Comment: Then you implemented the logic incorrectly. You need to allow for inserting an empty string into the Document.

Comment: thanks once again . code =if(isdigit()) followed by code for character limit n only no....when i was clearing the txt it was going in else part so i called super.replace() method which solved the issue . Great bro