Java DocumentFilter Issue
I am having an issue with DocumentFilter (or at least it seems that is what is causing the issue).
The code itself grabs files from a folder then allows me to rename them, the part that I am struggling with is it is also supposed to check each file to see if it follows a certain naming structure and if it does it is suppose to add that to the text fields.
I have some Int and Size filters for JTextFields that seemingly work properly, i.e they will not accept any letters and won't go over the max length. I have 2 of these filters serialFilter and sciFilter on different Text Fields. serialFilter works perfectly fine when I grab a String and use the setText function - keep in mind the text is always equal to the max size of the filter. sciFilter, however doesn't update the text. I have tests to ensure the size isn't over the max length.
Relevant(ish) code is as follows if anyone needs more let me know.
public class NewTest {
    JPanel panel;
    JLabel oldFileName, sciLabel, serialLabel;
    JTextField sciField, serialField;
    JButton accept;
    String sci, serial;

    public NewTest() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Set Drawing Number");
        
        //SEARCH FOLDER
        File f = getFolder();
        //===== ONLY INCLUDE IF 'f' IS A FILE
        FileFilter fileFilter = new FileFilter() {
            public boolean accept(File f) {   
                return f.isFile();
            }
        };
        
        File[] listOfFiles = f.listFiles(fileFilter);
        panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(null);
        panel.setBounds(700, 300, 0, 0);
        
        //===== SET UP DOCUMENT FILTERS =====
        DocumentFilter sciFilter = new SizeAndIntFilter(5);
        DocumentFilter serialFilter = new SizeAndIntFilter(4);
        
        //==== SETUP JPANEL =====
        sciField = new JTextField(5);
        ((AbstractDocument)sciField.getDocument()).setDocumentFilter(sciFilter);
        sciField.setBounds(110, 55, 45, 25);
        
        serialField = new JTextField(4);
        ((AbstractDocument)serialField.getDocument()).setDocumentFilter(serialFilter);
        serialField.setBounds(175, 55, 41, 25);
        
        oldFileName = new JLabel(listOfFiles[0].getName());
        oldFileName.setBounds(83, 5, 300, 25);
        
        String testThis = listOfFiles[0].getName();
        
        //SPLIT oldFileName BY DELIMITER "-" TO SEE IF IT IS FOLLOWING THE CURRENT NAMING STANDARD
        String[] testThisArray = testThis.split("-");
        
        sciField.setText(testThisArray[1]);
        serialField.setText(testThisArray[2]);
        
        accept = new JButton("Accept");
        accept.setBounds(375, 173, 100, 30);
        accept.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            int n = 0;
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                String[] checkNum = {"", ""};
                while(n < listOfFiles.length){
                    n++;
                    if(n < listOfFiles.length){
                        oldFileName.setText(listOfFiles[n].getName());
                        checkNum = listOfFiles[n].getName().split("-");
                        
                    }
                    else{
                        oldFileName.setText("NO MORE FILES");
                    }
                    break;
                }
                
                if(checkNum[1].length() == 5){
                    System.out.println(checkNum[1]);
                    sciField.setText(checkNum[1]);
                }
                
                if(checkNum[2].length() == 4){
                    serialField.setText(checkNum[2]);
                }
            }
        }); 
        
        panel.add(oldFileName);
        panel.add(sciField);
        panel.add(serialField);
        panel.add(accept);
        
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.setSize(500, 250);
        Dimension dim = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        frame.setLocation(dim.width/2-frame.getSize().width/2, dim.height/2-frame.getSize().height/2);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
    

    //===== MAIN =====
    public static void main(String[] args){
        //STARTS SetNumNoCheck()
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new NewTest(); //PUT FILE VARIABLE IN BRACKETS
            }
        }); 
    }
    
    //===== GET FOLDER =====
    public File getFolder(){
        int test = 0;
        //SELECT FOLDER WITH DRAWINGS YOU WISH TO RENAME
        JFileChooser folder = new JFileChooser();
        
        folder.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
        folder.setDialogTitle("Select Folder");
        folder.showDialog(null, "SELECT");
        
        File f = folder.getSelectedFile();
        //IF JFileChooser IS CLOSED - PATH WILL BE NULL : CLOSE PROGRAM
        if(f == null){
            System.exit(0);
        }

        return f;
    }
}

//SETS CHARACTER LIMIT & ALLOWS NUMERIC VALUES ONLY
class SizeAndIntFilter extends DocumentFilter {
    private int limit;    
    
    public SizeAndIntFilter(int limit) {
        this.limit = limit;
    }

    @Override
    public void insertString(FilterBypass fb, int offs, String str, AttributeSet a) throws BadLocationException {

        Document doc = fb.getDocument();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append(doc.getText(0, doc.getLength()));
        sb.insert(offs, str);

        if (test(sb.toString())) {
            if ((fb.getDocument().getLength() + str.length()) <= limit)
                super.insertString(fb, offs, str, a);
            else
                Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();
        }
        else {
            //WARN - only numeric values allowed
        }
   }
   
   private boolean test(String text) {
        try {
            Integer.parseInt(text);
            return true;
        } 
        catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void replace(FilterBypass fb, int offs, int length, String str, AttributeSet a) throws BadLocationException {
        Document doc = fb.getDocument();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append(doc.getText(0, doc.getLength()));
        sb.insert(offs, str);

        if (test(sb.toString())) {
            if ((fb.getDocument().getLength() + str.length()) - length > limit)
                super.replace(fb, offs, length, str.substring(0, limit-fb.getDocument().getLength()), a);
            else if ((fb.getDocument().getLength() + str.length()) - length <= limit)
                super.replace(fb, offs, length, str, a);
            else
                Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();
        }
        else {
            //WARN - only numeric values allowed
        }   
    }
}


I am certainly aware that this code is not the best written code and I know I'm sure there are things I'm doing I'm not supposed to but if you're able to get through my code and not want to murder me any help would be appreciated.
After a little testing it would seem that any numbers starting in 1 or 2 are able to be set for Filter sciField. while Filter serialField can start with any number and seems to work fine. This is the case when:
When I change the text 'manually' sciField.setText("12345")
When I use sci's filter on serialField it works properly.
When I use either filter on sciField it doesn't not work unless the number starts with 1 or 2.
This is an example of the code running through 3 files

I would murder you for not formatting the code in the first place /JK. Please could you edit your question and properly format your code, it is hard to read it even to make sense of it.

I assume “Y” is serialField.  Please edit your question and show the code that sets its text.  Also, you probably should include the code for the SizeAndIntFilter class.

I would start with the IntegerFilter here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76855700/131872. Then make the change to limit the length. If you still have a problem then post a proper [mre] demonstrating the problem. That is you need a frame with two text fields and the filter for each. There is no need for the KeyListeners. The point is to first get the filters working then worry about the rest of your application logic.

Hopefully that is more legible now.
@VGR - The code that sets the text is under the 'accept' button ActionListener. and the code for SizeAndIntFilter is the class is it not?

If valid values for sciField are always exactly 5 characters, you might want to consider something like new JFormattedTextField(new MaskFormatter("#####")), which would remove the need for a DocumentFilter entirely.

That may work well with IntegerFilter, thanks.

So I tried IntFilter. Both by adjusting my code and using yours @camickr both with no luck. I get the same result as before - it works with anything starting in 1 or 2 but nothing else...
I will also note it WILL allow it for the initial setup i.e it properly works for the first file no matter the number.

Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.

Code has been trimmed - Hopefully that helps. Thanks!

No the trimmed code doesn't help. You did not listen to the suggestion given on how to create an [mre]. The point of the MRE is to forget about your application and just get a simple text field on a frame working. Then you add back in some of your application logic. When/if it stops working you know what you just changed. I know the IntegerFilter works.

@camickr The issue is I know IntFilter works because it works for serialField so I am wondering why it's not working for sciFilter in this scenario. Now I apologize for not fully understanding MRE but to me this is the minimum I THOUGHT was necessary because the sciFilter works when it is first set. The issue arises from the second on. so I didn't think a simple TextField with a set statement wouldn't suffice.

Apologies to everyone who helped out. I am just getting into coding so my interpretation of the MRE was off.
I figured out the issue which I should have seen earlier when I noticed numbers starting with 1 and 2 worked. I did not realize that the TEXT I'm passing through in the following included both the value being set with the previous value appended - making it too large for an integer. I switched it to a Double and we are good.
`
private boolean test(String text) {
    try {
        //Integer.parseInt(text);
        Double.parseDouble(text);
        return true;
    } 
    catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        return false;
    }
}`

Thanks again and I will do my best to present code in the proper format in the future.

Check out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60745835/131872 for a "DigitFilter". This would be a better filter to use since you are not strictly testing for a Integer, but instead for integer digits. Also, note the answer is presented in the form of an MRE. It contains the class you want to test as well as a simple GUI to test the class. Simplifying the code makes it easier to find problems.
